# WSO2 API Manager: exceeded the allocated quota

Tags: api, wso2, throttling, quota

What does this message mean in  my log?

> INFO {org.wso2.carbon.throttle.core.RoleBasedAccessRateController} -
>   You cannot access this service since you have exceeded the allocated
>   quota. {org.wso2.carbon.throttle.core.RoleBasedAccessRateController}

My throtteling of service is set to unlimited, on service level as well on the backend (post/get).

We are using WSO2 AM 1.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check what Throttling tiers you have selected when creating the Application and the Subscription. Throttling will be done based on the most restrictive tier. i.e If you have selected  Bronze when creating the Application and Unlimited when creating the subscription, requests will only have the quota of a Bronze subscription.

Comment: I checked the "Unlimited" options by throtteling when publishing the service and added NO Authentication, making this service public. IMHO: the "Unauthenticated" role in the tiers.xml is enabled.

Comment: If Authentication is set to None, then Unauthenticated tier gets applied. That only allows 60 requests per a minute. You can edit the tiers.xml to change this limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have exceeded your throttle limit..When you create APIs you provide throttle limit..(eg: silver/gold..)

Comment: Can it be the issue, that my services is 'public', not authenticated? I see in the tiers.xml file: <throttle:ID throttle:type="ROLE">Unauthenticated</throttle:ID>, which has restrictions ?